# Trying to pass two ArrayList that are populated via Firebase in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have the following Activity that needs to populate two ArrayLists via Firebase Realtime Database as such:

```
pickListener = pickQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot pickSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            Picks pick = new Picks(pickSnapshot);
           
            pickList.add(pick);

        }

    } 

}


mListener = pickQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot pickSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            Game game = new Game(pickSnapshot);
           
            gameList.add(pick);

            if (counter == dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()) {

                adapter = new GameAdapter(PicksheetActivity.this, gameList, pickList); <---- ISSUE HERE, PASSES NULL ARRAY!? 

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

        }

    } 

}
```

So what is happening in the code above, or should happen, is that when the `pickList` and `gameList` get populated, then and only then should it invoke the Adapter to populate the view (list of items).

How do I achieve this, is there a way to put a completion handler in Android, so that when one list populates the next list is then populated and then invoke the adapter?

Comment: I see no difference between the provided listeners, you have `pickQuery.addValueEventListener`  that is set to two different variables, but the same listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both callbacks assigned to pickListener and mListener runs parallelly . but mListener code rely on result from pickListener code but  we can't expect result from it while running Asynchronously .By placing second listener  inside method we can run one after another to get desired result.

```
 pickListener = pickQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    
            for (DataSnapshot pickSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    
                Picks pick = new Picks(pickSnapshot);
               
                pickList.add(pick);
                
                
            }
           getGameList(pickList);
        } 
    
    }
    
    public void getGameList(List<Pick> pickList){
    
    mListener = pickQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    
            for (DataSnapshot pickSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    
                Game game = new Game(pickSnapshot);
               
                gameList.add(pick);
    
                if (counter == dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()) {
    
                    adapter = new GameAdapter(PicksheetActivity.this, gameList, pickList);  
    
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    
                }
    
            }
    }
    
        } 
    
    }
```

Comment: Im getting an error `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference` which Im not sure why? The only thing I can imagine is because I moved it into its own function.

Comment: double check "recyclerView" initiated using findViewById().@Learn2Code

Comment: So it would seem that the recyclerView and initiating it now needs to exist/declared in the "new" `getGameList(List<PIck>pickList) function`. Which was unexpected, once I did move the recyclerView into `getGameList` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your code, you are performing two database calls to getting two different types of objects. What is actually happening, both requests are happening in parallel. Since both operations are asynchronous, meaning that both will take some time to finish loading the data, you'll never know which one finishes first.

In order to solve this problem, you need to wait for both operations to complete. So the simplest solution would be to use nested listeners, meaning that you should move the second database call inside the first one, or vice-versa. Once the second database call is complete, you can then invoke the Adapter to populate the view. Please also notice to use addListenerForSingleValueEvent instead of addValueEventListener, to get the data only once. If need to have real-time updates, then be aware that the result from a database call will be a `DataSnapshot` object that will contain all data that the Query is returning. So be aware to handle this situation too.

The second, newer, and more practical option that you have is to use  [Tasks#whenAllSuccess()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAllSuccess(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E...)) method as in the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query firstQuery = rootRef...
Query secondQuery = rootRef...

Task firstTask = firstQuery.get();
Task secondTask = secondQuery.get();

Task combinedTask = Tasks.whenAllSuccess(firstTask, secondTask).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Object> list) {
         //Do what you need to do with your list
    }
});
```

Comment: for the first proposed solution, can you please provide code, I am new to Android and in Swift I use completionhandlers to achieve that, does Android offer that? But if you could please provide a code sample on how to nest them in Android please. Lastly for the code sample provided, is that for Kotlin? Regretfully I an using java?

Comment: It's almost the same as in Swift. So to achieve that, you should simply move the second database call inside the first one, right after the first for loop end. And no, it's not Kotlin, it's Java.

Comment: Yes I have, I have awarded the answer provided by androidlearner above

Comment: Can please explain how you did that, as querying the database in parallel will never provide an accurate result. None of the listeners will know about the completion of the other.

Comment: Oh sorry, you are correct, what I did was to create a counter which increments on the each child value and when the counter == snapshot count then make the call to the second function to get the game data. `if (counter == dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()) { getGamesList(pickList); }`

Comment: That might work, but never that solution because it will never succeed, as no listener knows about the completion of the other. In my answer, you are 100% sure that both listeners are finished getting data ;)

Comment: So I hope you reconsider the right answer and mark it accordingly.

Comment: Ill have to look more into your solution, I just didnt have the time, but everything is working as expected with my solution so ill keep it for now until i have the time to dive deeper into ur answer. BTW thx for posting ur solution, I hope it helps others who have the ability to implement it now.

Comment: You're very welcome. I hope you'll also find some time to try my solution, in the same way, I found time to answer your question ;)

Comment: Hey. Have you found some time to try it?